# When do you hear the Ping sound of the lid sealing?

Tags: food-safety, food-science, food-preservation

I am new to canning. I made applesauce this morning and I pulled them out of the water bath and put them on a towel on my counter to seal, but I never heard the "ping" sound of them sealing shut. When does that usually occur? In the water bath? After the water bath? And if so, how long after you pull it out does that usually take? 5 min or 2 hours?

Answer (score 3):

The real goal is for the lid to turn concave. They're manufactured to be convex (sticking up in the middle). If they're concave on the jar, that means there's a difference in pressure between the inside and outside of the jar causing the lid to be sucked downward.

If the jar has cooled significantly, and the lid is still convex, you could try pushing down lightly on the lid. If it doesn't stay down, you don't have a good seal.

Comment: Better:  even if it stays down, but you can pull it up with a single fingernail, then it isn't sealed.  A properly sealed jar is sealed much too tight for you to gain leverage via your fingernail on that tiny lip.  I myself need to use an appropriated beer–bottle opener.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real exact time it happens (at least in my kitchen).  I've had some jars that come out of the water with the lid depressed and others that take many hours.  By the next morning, they should be cooled with the lids depressed.  If they aren't, then they should be reprocessed or refrigerated to be eaten right away.  :)

Comment: Some of the lids don't make much of a ping sound when they go concave.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had mine ping almost immediately up to an hour later, give or take. Press on the middle and if you hear or see any movement, it didn’t seal. If it’s flat/ slightly concave and doesn’t move, it’s sealed. Did you put the lids on and only finger tighten the rings? After you take them out, carefully (so not to get burned) tighten the rings. That’s important.